# calling function by string from inside class function in python

Tags: python

How can I call outside function from inside class function like below?

I know that locals() work when there is no class.

```
def fn_outside(a):
    print('a:{}'.format(a))
class T:
    def t(self):
        fns = ['fn_outside']
        for fn in fns:
           locals()[fn](1)
t = T()
t.t()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can call directly?     `def t(self): fn_outside(1)` ?

Comment: Why on earth are you doing `locals()['fn_outside'](1)` ?? Just use `fn_outside(1)`

Comment: Why use local(), simply call it fn_outside(1). Then make a object of class T() and call the t(self) method

Comment: I need to call multiple functions with string names. I edited the body to reflect.

Comment: If you *need* to call functions based on strings, you should probably create a dict that maps strings to functions.

Comment: Instead of `fns = ['fn_outside']`, use `fns = [fn_outside]` so you can just call the functions, without a name lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would call it, there are supposed to be no Quotation marks
around the function, rather you can simply put the function name and then loop through the list, in the end you can put `()`

```
def fn_outside(a):
    print('a:{}'.format(a))
class T:
    def t(self):
        fns = [fn_outside]
        for fn in fns:
           fn(1)
t = T()
t.t()
```